# Transform data types in parts of a column

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am retrieving data through Power Query from an Oracle DB live to an Excel workbook. In PQ, under the "Transform" tab, there is a function to change the data type of a column, that I use to get all the decimal numbers displayed. In the M-code the function is called TransformColumnTypes. However I have some strings in the data that I cannot change to decimal number and produce an error. Is there a way to exclude these? Because the function takes the whole column at the moment.

#### Before applying function

[image: Before applying function]

#### Function producing error

[image: Function producing error]

#### Code

[image: Code]

Comment: No. But if your strings are only in the first row, and you want them to be the column headers, you can promote them before setting the type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. If you have multiple types within a column, text is the only one that doesn't produce errors.
But if it is only the first row like in your image, promoting it to header before setting the column type will fix the issue.